# jquery selectbox plugin cannot navigate via tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin which turns select dropdown boxes into nicer looking versions. However, I've just noticed that when you try to tab through the form inputs, once you get to one of these styled selectboxes, the ability to tab through stops.

That's really bad craic because I'm using quite a few of those selectboxes through my site and I've only noticed this issue. Does anyone have an idea if this is easy to fix?

the code for the plugin is here:

http://code.google.com/p/select-box/issues/list

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UgYU4/

code:

```
<label class="inputLabel" for="postcode">Post/Zip Code:</label>
<input type="text" name="postcode" size = "11" maxlength = "10" id="postcode" class="loginformInput" />

<label class="inputLabel" for="country">Country:&nbsp;<span class="alert">*</span></label>
<div id="logincountry">
<select name="zone_country_id" id="country" onchange="update_zone(this.form);">
  <option value="">Please Choose Your Country</option>
  <option value="222" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="103">ROI Republic of Ireland</option>
  <option value="223">United States</option>
  <option value="13">Australia</option>
</select>
</div><script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#country").selectbox();
});
</script>


<label class="inputLabel" for="email-address">Email Address:&nbsp;<span class="alert">*    </span></label>
<input type="text" name="email_address" size = "41" maxlength= "96" id="email-address" class="loginformInput" />
```

Comment: Is anyone able to help me out with this? Pretty please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about keyboard/navigation support, you should instead use my jQuery plugin, [SelectBoxIt](http://www.selectboxit.com).  Also, regarding tab indexes, SelectBoxIt supports this out of the box.